# Group data by latest date per month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I store data on a daily basis in the following table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DemoTable
(
    ReportDate                  DATE                NOT NULL,
    IdOne                       INT                 NOT NULL,
    IdTwo                       INT                 NOT NULL,
    NumberOfThings              INT                 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

    CONSTRAINT PK_DemoTable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ReportDate, IdOne, IdTwo)
)
```

I'd like to report on this but only pull out data (sum of NumberOfThings) for the latest date we have for each month.

Example data

```
INSERT INTO DemoTable
(ReportDate, IdOne, IdTwo, NumberOfThings)
VALUES
('2016-11-02',1,2,2),   ('2016-11-02',1,3,2),   ('2016-11-01',1,2,20),  ('2016-11-01',1,3,20),
('2016-10-31',1,2,2),   ('2016-10-31',1,3,2),   ('2016-10-30',1,2,20),  ('2016-10-30',1,3,20),  ('2016-10-29',1,2,200), ('2016-10-29',1,3,200),
('2016-09-30',1,2,5),   ('2016-09-30',1,3,5),   ('2016-09-29',1,2,55),  ('2016-09-29',1,3,55)
```

So for this data I want to see:

```
 2016-11-02 | 4 
 2016-10-31 | 4
 2016-09-30 | 10
```

Thanks

Comment: How latest date for nov 2016 is 02 nov?

Comment: gotcha i took your initial data.. now its fixed

Comment: Yes, sorry I spotted the dodgy data and fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RANK()` to spot the latest date rows on each month, and them sum them .

```
SELECT s.ReportDate,SUM(s.NumberOfThings)
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(t.ReportDate), MONTH(t.ReportDate) ORDER BY t.ReportDate DESC) as rnk
    FROM DemoTable t) s
WHERE s.rnk = 1
GROUP BY s.ReportDate
```

Comment: Thanks.
There's a small mistake, you need s.ReportDate,SUM(s.NumberOfThings) not t. in the first line.
This works.

Comment: Yea, typo .. no problem @user2436996

Answer (score 1):

You can use query like this

```
select ReportDate, sum(NumberofThings) as SumNumberofThings from DemoTable where ReportDate in
(
select   max(ReportDate) MaxReportDate from DemoTable
group by datepart(yy,reportdate), datepart(m,reportdate)
)
group by ReportDate
```

Comment: This works well, but I had already accepted the answer from sagi. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A typical method involves `row_number()`.  The only trick is using date functions to get the year and the month:

```
select dt.*
from (select dt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(ReportDate), month(ReportDate)
                                order by ReportDate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from DemoTable dt
     ) dt
where seqnum = 1;
```

If there are duplicates per date, you would just do the same thing with aggregation:

```
select dt.ReportDate, dt.NumberOfThings
from (select dt.ReportDate, sum(NumberOfThings) as NumberOfThings,
             row_number() over (partition by year(ReportDate), month(ReportDate)
                                order by ReportDate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from DemoTable dt
      group by NumberOfThings
     ) dt
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Down Vote reason is  Please read the question once again, user wants latest records sum, not the latest records

Comment: @Srinath . . . I don't think the duplicates were obvious in the phrasing of the question:

Comment: It defiantly wasn't . No need to downvote @Srinath .

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate your data so as to get the sum per date. Then rank your records by date within month. Then pick the best ranked records.

```
SELECT
  ReportDate, 
  SumNumberOfThings
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    ReportDate, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(ReportDate), MONTH(ReportDate)
                       ORDER BY ReportDate DESC) AS rn
    SUM(NumberOfThings) AS SumNumberOfThings
  FROM DemoTable
  GROUP BY ReportDate
) ranked
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ReportDate;
```

Comment: Oops, seems I was a bit late with my answer. I like sagi's answer for its cleanliness.